# Why Firefox is not displaying a space with two BRs?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on this [website](http://www.casaebase.com.br) and displaying posts from the database. I'm replacing the `\r\n\r\n` with `<br/><br/>`. Works as expected in Opera, Chrome and IE, but in Firefox, it only jump one line as if only one `<br/>` (but I looked at source code and has two).

I'm doing something wrong or Firefox is not working properly on this? I'm using Firefox 7.

The HTML generated. The double `br` are not displayed properly.

`<span class='conteudo'>No dia 19 de novembro, a <strong>Brasilit</strong> irá realizar uma palestra promovendo o lançamento de suas novas linhas de telhas <strong>Colonial</strong>, <strong>Shingle</strong> e <strong>Top</strong> <strong>Steel</strong>.<br /><br />A palestra é voltada para os profissionais que atuam na área de coberturas.<br /><br />Maiores informações podem ser obtidas com os vendedores.</span>`

Comment: Can you put the HTML code into your question, so we can see some context.  Don't put the entire page, but a small amount before and after the problem area would be useful to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At http://www.casaebase.com.br/css/default.css, the following declaration appears:

```
.post .conteudo br {
    display: block; /* <-- Causes the issue at Firefox*/
    height: 1px;
}
```

This `display` property should be `inline`. An empty `block` element (ie, an element with `display:block`, without visible content) will be hidden in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to remove this part of CSS. Was only an test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've got CSS overriding the normal behaviour of the `<br>` tag.

Looking in Firebug, when I navigate to the `<br>` tag, I see this:

```
.post .conteudo br {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
}
```

If you remove these styles, the `<br>` works as normal.

I'm not sure why you've chosen to style the `<br>` tag at all, but this is the result of that styling.